# Apply gradient to bottom of container if height is greater than X pixels

Tags: css

**Note: I am not simply asking how to put a gradient to the bottom of a div. I'm asking how to only show the gradient if the div is greater than a certain height.**

I currently have this:

https://jsfiddle.net/fwtj44bj/3/

I want to apply this gradient to the bottom of any `.container` that is great than 100px in height:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&0+0,1+100

Meaning that the second row of the first `.container` should have the gradient over the boxes, but the second `.container` should have no gradient.

How can this be done?

My thinking is to somehow make use of `max-height`, but I'm not sure how.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 332px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: You'd need Javascript for achieving this.

Comment: I'm almost 100% certain you'll need javascript for this. At least if you want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without javascript. Use `:after` selector.Position your `container` as `relative` and then offset the :after element by 100px.

```css
.container {
  width: 332px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this example the gradient grows in height as the height of the container grows. So as more boxes are added the height of the gradient changes because it's positioned from the top, not the bottom.

Comment: Yes. And what do you think OP expects? He didn't mention more rows , and he didn't specify how it should behave if there are more box elements.

Comment: I think it is implied - otherwise why not just add it to the first container, and any other similar containers manually?

Comment: Good approach but keep in mind it is not a dynamic solution. with change in box height (due to content) or number of rows it will fail.

Answer (score 5):

You need javascript to get the height of div. after that you can set a class that will add gradient.
If you want gradient over boxes then we use ::after pseudo class.

have a look please

```js
var heights = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
for (var i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
    var height = heights[i].offsetHeight;
    if(height > 104){
     heights[i].className += " gradient";
    }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 332px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  padding:0px;
  position:relative;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&0+0,1+100 */
.gradient::after{
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  content:' ';
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add jQuery to your project you can do this by adding a css class after checking each .container div's height.

https://jsfiddle.net/fwtj44bj/5/

```
$(".container").each(function(){
  if ($(this).height() > 100) {
    $(this).addClass("gradient");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
I edited my answer so the pseudo element have `height:calc(100% - 100px);`  instead of just `height:100%`, this way you don't need to have `overflow:hidden` on `.container`

How about this: [check fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ukegddc/4/)

```
.container{
  width: 332px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  position:relative;
}
.container:after{
  content:' ';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 100px);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,0,255,1) 100%);
}
```

Obvious limitations: `.container` should have `position:relative`  <strike>and `overflow:hidden`</strike>.